# Why is maven running the same pom differently on two computers?

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, javadoc

Me and my workmate are trying to call the **same Maven command (mvn site)** on exactly the **same pom** and getting totally **different output**.

The code of which we think is going wrong, is the javadoc-plugin we added lately:

```
    <!-- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/ -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.javadoc.plugin}</version>
        <configuration>
          <destDir>javadoc</destDir>
          <charset>UTF-8</charset>
          <docencoding>UTF-8</docencoding>
          <doctitle>${project.name} API Documentation
            ${project.version}.${svn_revision}</doctitle>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <failonerror>false</failonerror>
          <footer>Specification: ${specification.title}</footer>
          <header>${project.name} API Documentation
            ${project.version}.${svn_revision}</header>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <use>true</use>
          <version>true</version>
          <windowtitle>${project.name} API Documentation
            ${project.version}.${svn_revision}</windowtitle>
          <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Running this **gets me the correct javadoc-generation** in the targeted folder. When I pushed it to the svn repository and my mate downloaded, it was not working for him.

There is no Error and no warning, **it just does not generate the javadoc**.

**Additional info:**

1. We are not using any local settings.xml.
2. The output of mvn site -X (debug mode) does not make any difference regarding the javadoc-plugin.
3. He already reinstalled jdk and re-set his $JAVA_HOME.
4. Same Maven version

What could be the problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Same JDK, same Maven Version pinnned all plugins ? If you call site there many plugins related...

Comment: Yes, everything is the same. we have a local repository with an eclipse installation with all the plugins we use. We already 'updated' our eclipse to the latest version available there.

Comment: Are you calling from command line? Which i assume?

Comment: We both called from command line AND from eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `mvn -v` to make sure you're using the same Maven and Java versions. The command will print the paths to the Java runtime, make sure they are same and correct.

If that checks out, run `mvn help:effective-pom` to see what Maven will execute. Redirect the output on both machines to a file and compare them.

Next, try to invoke the plugin directly from the command line. If that works, attaching to the life cycle doesn't work for some reason. If it doesn't work, check for error messages and use `-X` to check the plugin configuration.

If everything else fails, delete your local Maven repository (or at least the involved plugins).

Comment: +1 for deleting the local repo as part of the troubleshooting. If it doesn't fix the problem, it might give errors or warnings to show you where it is.

Comment: We needed to reload the whole project, including eclipse and even svn. Thank you for your help though